# Using activations from a specific layer to compute a function, which is used further down in the TensorFlow computational graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Inorder to retrieve the activation from a specific layer, I understand that we can use

`layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('network/layer_conv5/Relu:0')
activation = session.run(layer, feed_dict={x: images_test[0:10, :, :, :]})`

But, suppose, I just dont want to end the computation by seeing the activation. What I would like to do is, while the computational graph is `run`, I want to peek into some activations (say `act`, which is a tensor) and then have `v = func(act)`, and use `v` somewhere deeper down the network, like in the loss function.

If I were to do this in Caffe, I could just tap the activations that come to a layer (`bottom` to a layer), compute my function and then pass it up (`top`) if this layer and use it somewhere else in the network.

How can I do this in TensorFlow?